# Merge 2 arrays at specific indices in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-merge

I have a `target` array, say: `[A, C, E, F, H]`.
I have another array `toMerge` that needs to be merged into `target`, say: `[B, D, G, I]`.
I also have an integer array that tells the indices of target array where `toMerge` items will be finally merged at, say: `[1, 3, 6, 8]`.

I need a function that will merge `toMerge` array into `target` in-place, at indices specified by the `indices` array so that `target` eventually looks like

```
[A(0), B(1), C(2), D(3), E(4), F(5), G(6), H(7), I(8)]
```

I tried using inbuilt array splice functions to iterate over indices array and splice(add) each at each index. Something along the lines:

```
for (let i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {
    target.splice(indices[i], 0, toMerge[i]);
}
```

I am looking for any solution that can do it more efficiently and elegantly.

It gets trickier if the `indices` array is **unsorted** or worse - **reverse-sorted**! For e.g.,

```
toMerge: [I, G, D, B]
indices: [8, 6, 3, 1]
```

after applying the above algorithm, `target` ends up being:

```
target: [A, B, C, E, D, F, H, I, G]
```

One solution to this is to sort the `indices` array in non-decreasing order along with the `toMerge` array ensuring the sequence is honored, further complicating things.

Comment: The problem is that the array indexes change after you do the first splice, since everything after the splice moves up. You should splice them in reverse order.

Comment: Your existing code seems to be efficient and fairly elegant.  I don't think you can make it more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

### Unsorted indices + absolute

If you are working with unsorted indices: you would have to "zip" (need to first `transpose`) the array to be merged and its corresponding indices. Once you have a matrix of `[index, value][]` sorted, you can perform an in-order splice.

```js
const transpose = (a) => a[0].map((_, i) => a.map(r => r[i]));
const sortByIndex = (a) => a.sort((x, y) => x[0] - y[0]);

const absoluteMerge = (a, toMerge, unsortedIndices) => {
  const res = [...a];
  const sorted = sortByIndex(transpose([unsortedIndices, toMerge]));
  for (let i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++) {
    res.splice(sorted[i][0], 0, sorted[i][1]);
  }
  return res;
};

const a = ['A', 'C', 'E', 'F', 'H'], b = ['I', 'G', 'D', 'B'];

const c = absoluteMerge(a, b, [8, 6, 3, 1]);

console.log(...c); // A B C D E F G H I
```

---

### Original response

If you are working with absolute indices (as you are), you can insert the items in-order; but if you use relative indices, you need to reverse the insertion.

#### Absolute merge

```js
const absoluteMerge = (a, b, insertionIndices) => {
  const res = [...a];
  for (let i = 0; i < insertionIndices.length; i++) {
    res.splice(insertionIndices[i], 0, b[i]);
  }
  return res;
};

const a = ['A', 'C', 'E', 'F', 'H'], b = ['B', 'D', 'G'];

const c = absoluteMerge(a, b, [1, 3, 6]);

console.log(...c); // A B C D E F G H
```

#### Relative merge

```js
const relativeMerge = (a, b, insertionIndices) => {
  const res = [...a];
  for (let i = insertionIndices.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    res.splice(insertionIndices[i], 0, b[i]);
  }
  return res;
};

const a = ['A', 'C', 'E', 'F', 'H'], b = ['B', 'D', 'G'];

const c = relativeMerge(a, b, [1, 2, 4]);

console.log(...c); // A B C D E F G H
```

Comment: I have updated the problem where the indices might not be in non-decreasing sorted order. This is exactly what I implemented and doesn't work for unsorted indices.

Comment: @user3392450 did you still want absolute indices?

Comment: Absolute indices is what I will have. Think of it as undo/redo problem where user selects a bunch of letters and deletes them. I capture the letters and their original indices during delete, and when user chooses to 'undo', I want to re-instate the original array before the delete ops. In this situation all I will have during undo are the absolute indices and not the relative ones.

Comment: @user3392450 I updated my response.

Answer (score 1):

An one-liner with sorting the indices and toMerge:

```js
const target = [...'ACEFH'], toMerge = [...'IGDB'], indices = [8,6,3,1];

toMerge.map((c,i) => [indices[i],c]).sort(([a],[b]) => a-b).forEach(([i, c]) => target.splice(i, 0, c));

console.log(...target);
```

```
Cycles: 1000000 / Chrome/117
-----------------------------------------
Alexander   193/min  1.0x  203  215  193
Polywhirl   218/min  1.1x  230  257  218
-----------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark
```

```html
<script benchmark="1000000">

const toMerge = [...'IGDB'], indices = [8,6,3,1];

// @benchmark Polywhirl
const transpose = (a) => a[0].map((_, i) => a.map(r => r[i]));
const sortByIndex = (a) => a.sort((x, y) => x[0] - y[0]);

const absoluteMerge = (a, toMerge, unsortedIndices) => {
  const res = [...a];
  const sorted = sortByIndex(transpose([unsortedIndices, toMerge]));
  for (let i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++) {
    res.splice(sorted[i][0], 0, sorted[i][1]);
  }
  return res;
};

absoluteMerge([...'ACEFH'], toMerge, indices);

// @benchmark Alexander
const target = [...'ACEFH'];
toMerge.map((c,i) => [indices[i],c]).sort(([a],[b]) => a-b).forEach(([i, c]) => target.splice(i, 0, c));
target;
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js"></script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately indexOf will be linear complexity and using it within forEach squares it overall. It is a one-liner and looks elegant and precise though. Thanks.

Comment: @p40m3th3us fixed, updated with a better one-liner

Comment: @p40m3th3us added a benchmark

Answer (score 0):

Thinking on sorted, reverse-sorted, and a possibility of unsorted list `toMerge`, at first we need to merge the `toMerge` with the `indices` list and sort, then we can merge these values with the `target` list, for example:

```js
const mergeArraysByIndex = (target, toMerge, indices) => {
  // Create an array of objects with keys and values
  const toMergeWithIndex = toMerge.map((key, index) => ({key, value: indices[index]}));

  // Sort the array of objects by value
  toMergeWithIndex.sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value);

  // Create a final object with sorted keys and values
  const resultObject = {};
  toMergeWithIndex.forEach(item => {
    resultObject[item.key] = item.value;
  });

  //Merge the arrays together
  return Object.values(resultObject).reduce((acc, index, i) => {
    acc.splice(index, 0, Object.keys(resultObject)[i]);
    return acc;
  }, [...target])
}

//First example (sorted!)
console.log(mergeArraysByIndex(['A', 'C', 'E', 'F', 'H'], ['B', 'D', 'G'], [1, 3, 6]));

//Second example (reverse-sorted!)
console.log(mergeArraysByIndex(['A', 'C', 'E', 'F', 'H'], ['I', 'G', 'D', 'B'], [8, 6, 3, 1]));

//Third example (unsorted!)
console.log(mergeArraysByIndex(['A', 'C', 'E', 'F', 'H'], ['D', 'I', 'G', 'B'], [3, 8, 6, 1]));
```

Or in a resumed way:

```js
const mergeArraysByIndex = (target, toMerge, indices) => {
  return indices
    .map((index, i) => ({ key: toMerge[i], index }))
    .sort((a, b) => a.index - b.index)
    .reduce((acc, { key, index }) => {
      acc.splice(index, 0, key);
      return acc;
    }, [...target]);
};

//First example (sorted!)
console.log(mergeArraysByIndex(['A', 'C', 'E', 'F', 'H'], ['B', 'D', 'G'], [1, 3, 6]));

//Second example (reverse-sorted!)
console.log(mergeArraysByIndex(['A', 'C', 'E', 'F', 'H'], ['I', 'G', 'D', 'B'], [8, 6, 3, 1]));

//Third example (unsorted!)
console.log(mergeArraysByIndex(['A', 'C', 'E', 'F', 'H'], ['D', 'I', 'G', 'B'], [3, 8, 6, 1]));
```